# Lorentzian function with exponent other than 2

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Is there a name for a "generalized" form of the Lorentzian function, where the exponent *a* in
$$
1\over(x^a+1)
$$
is a free-ranging parameter?

I'm interested in this for curve-fitting power-law phenomenon in the frequency domain. After a long time Googling, it seems that "Lorentzian function" strictly refers to when a=2. Apologies in advance if this is super simple question.

Comment: I have never seen a name associated with this function. However, "Generalized Lorentzian function" sounds nice to me.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro that would be great, at least to make Googling it easier. Have you seen it being used in other contexts? I'd really appreciate if you could point me to something like that.

Comment: No, sorry, never seen anything like that. That function, with a=2, arises as the Poisson kernel for the half space, however. You might try looking in that direction